# Call Jquery function after asp.net grid is loaded

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to call a jQuery function once the ASP.Net GridView is displayed. I have tried ready/load functions but none works for me.

the grid is inside Update Panel

```html
<asp:GridView ID="grdNumberPlan" runat="server" 
    CssClass="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped rt"         
    Visible="false">
</asp:GridView>
```

```js
$('#<%=grdNumberPlan.ClientID%>').ready(function () {
    alert('hello');
});

$('#<%=grdNumberPlan.ClientID%>').load(function () {
    alert('hello');
});
```

**aspx.cs code**

```
protected void ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (ddlHLR.SelectedValue == "0")
            {
                ((UIMaster)Page.Master).SetMessage(MessageType.Warnining, "Kindly select HLR");
                grdNumberPlan.DataSource = null;
                grdNumberPlan.DataBind();
                rowNewRanges.Visible = false;
                grdNumberPlan.Visible = false;
                return;
            }

            if (ddlCity.SelectedValue == "0")
            {
                ((UIMaster)Page.Master).SetMessage(MessageType.Warnining, "Select the city");
                grdNumberPlan.DataSource = null;
                grdNumberPlan.DataBind();
                rowNumPlanSum.Visible = false;
                grdNumberPlan.Visible = false;
                return;
            }

            //rangeList();

            NumberingPlan objNumberingPlan = new NumberingPlan();
            objNumberingPlan.CityID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCity.SelectedValue);
            objNumberingPlan.HlrID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlHLR.SelectedValue);
            objNumberingPlan.ExclusiveType = Convert.ToInt32(ddlIssuanceType.IsExclusive.ToString());
            objNumberingPlan.Operation_Type = OperationType.Get;

            InventoryManagementServiceClient client = new InventoryManagementServiceClient();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = client.GetNumberingPlanRanges(objNumberingPlan).Tables[0];
            grdNumberPlan.Visible = true;
            rowNumPlanSum.Visible = true;
            grdNumberPlan.DataSource = dt;
            grdNumberPlan.DataBind();

            ///Fill NDC dropdown list
            ///
            NDC objNDC = new NDC();
            objNDC.HLRID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlHLR.SelectedValue);
            objNDC.CityID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCity.SelectedValue);
            objNDC.Operation_Type = OperationType.Get;

            DataTable dtNDC = new DataTable();
            serviceClient = new CommonServiceClient();
            dtNDC = serviceClient.GetNDC(objNDC).Tables[0];
            //GlobalMethods.FillDropDownList(dtNDC, ddlNDC, "NDC", "NDC_ID");
            GlobalMethods.FillDropDownList(dtNDC, ddlNDC, "NDC", "NDC");

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:fnPopUp();", true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ((UIMaster)Page.Master).SetMessage(MessageType.Error, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why not put this in document.ready function ?

Comment: also not working from there

Comment: alert('hello'); is not working in document.ready ?

Comment: its working in document.ready but not after grid is loaded

Comment: How are you populating the GridView? In the sample code, it is not visible and as such would not render.

Comment: @Kami after binding i make it visible

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   callYourFunction();
});
```

or call javascript funtion from codebehind, after gridview bind

```
grdNumberPlan.DataSource=yourDataTable;
grdNumberPlan.DataBind();
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:FUNCTIONNAME(); ", true);
```

Comment: how many records are you displaying  at a time ?, If is taking long time, so call function with  using  `.delay()` or `setInterval`

Comment: `RegisterStartupScript` is correct, something else is wrong here. Instead of `Alert` use `Console.Log`. If you got other JavaScript/JQuery in the page there could be an issue in that causing any subsequent code to break.

Comment: populating around 100 records

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to comment. So I am posting as a new answer. In the RegisterStartupScript code, remove "javascript:" and try placing an alert statement.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "functionName(); ", true);
```

or

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "alert('In function'); ", true);
```